# Making a JDialog always on top of application

Tags: java, modal-dialog, parent, jdialog

I'm making a program that requires this jdialog box to always be focused and on top, ie: make the ding sound when i click on the parent window. here's what i have so far:

```
JDialog dialog = new JDialog();
//      dialog.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
        dialog.setSize(400, 220);
        dialog.setLocationRelativeTo(relativeTo); //relativeTo is the name of parent frame
        dialog.setVisible(true);
//      dialog.setModalityType(Dialog.ModalityType.APPLICATION_MODAL);
//      dialog.setModal(true);
```

(the commented things are those i have tried unsuccessfully...)

how would i make this dialog box ontop of the parent window? any help would be great! thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to set the dialog's owner and make the dialog modal:

```
JDialog dialog = new JDialog(parentFrame, true); // owner, modal
```

Comment: how would i set the parent?

Comment: @wbAnon updated my answer, you can pass the owner in the constructor